# Bazel run_shell action to call a .bat file

Tags: bash, bazel

Let me preface by saying I am new to Bazel, currently only running some very simple exercises to get a hang of it.

I am trying to use the run_shell action in my rules.bzl file to run a .bat file (which calls a .tcl script that generates a Vitis workspace based on some provided inputs). By itself, the .bat works fine and does its job.

However, when I run my target from the BUILD file with this rule, nothing happens. I get no errors and Bazel just keeps running forever with my custom progress_message on display.
[Screenshot of running bazel build in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYzmq.png)
This is what the run_shell actions looks like in the rules.bzl file:

```
ctx.actions.run_shell(
    command = "C:/Git/bazel_test/generate_project.bat",         
    outputs = [ checkpoint, log_file, journal_file ],
    progress_message = "vitis generate workspace",
  )
```

I noticed Bazel calls bash.exe to run the command that calls the .bat file. I tested running the .bat from bash.exe in cmd directly, and that works well.
I tried other experiments, like running a *tool*.bat from bazel, but again, nothing seems to be happening. If i run the same command from bash.exe in cmd, I can run the tool.bat.

Does anyone know if I am missing something for this seemingly trivial command? Would greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The correct interpreter for .bat files is `cmd`, not `bash`.

Comment: ...mind, you can typically start `cmd` (or, otherwise, a batch file) _from_ bash, but doing so doesn't look like `c:/anything`. Do you know whose version of bash-for-Windows you have? (How Windows paths are mapped to UNIX ones is quite different between implementations).

Comment: Alternately, does Bazel give you an option to run an executable, instead of running a shell? Invoking your .bat file _as an executable_ is likely to just do the right thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your replies. I am running everything on Windows. For this purpose I installed `MSYS2` for `bash`. I call the Bazel `build` command from `cmd`.   

This is the command I see Bazel running: `executing command C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c C:/Git/bazel_test/generate_project.bat` 
which does nothing.

If I run `C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c C:/Git/bazel_test/generate_project.bat`, which is essentially the same command, in `cmd`, it works fine. That is why it is baffling to me.